# Is: grandparent.parents.children association chaining not correct in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm having trouble figuring out the proper way of retrieving all children of multiple parents through **association chaining**.

To simplify I have three models:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

After creating a few objects I tired to use the example from rails guides (association basics: 4.3.3.4 includes):

```
Customer.first.invoices.line_items
```

It returns:

```
undefined method `line_items' for #<Customer::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy
```

Is grandparent.parents.children not usable?

**EDIT**

I'm not searching for the grandparent.parents.first.children, but all children of all parents in the collection, rails guides state:

> If you frequently retrieve line items directly from customers (@customer.orders.line_items),

As a valid operation, I would like to know if that is a mistake.

**FINAL** As stated in the comments of the selected answer: in ActiveRecord: scopes are chainable but associations are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `customer.invoices.line_items` cannot work the way you want to, since the `has_many` always is linked to a single record. but you can achieve what you want (if I understand correctly) using `has_many through` 
 as follows:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices
  has_many :line_items, through: :invoices
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

and now you can write:

```
customer.line_items
```

and it will return all `line_items` which are connected to a customer's invoices.

Comment: I'm aware of that, what interests me is that chaining associations is available.

Comment: You can chain scopes, but not associations. So you could write `customer.invoices.active` but not `customer.invoices.line_items` because a scope works on a relation, and an association on a single record (e.g. a single invoice).

Comment: This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
Customer.first.invoices.first.line_items
```

Or if you want all of the data together, you can do something like:

```
results = Customer.first.invoices.includes(:line_items)
```

Then you may access data with no `DB` call, by looping results. For first data ex: `results.first.line_items`

Hope it helps!

Comment: That is not the thing I'm wondering about, check the edit above :)

Comment: @quad As I have mentioned in my answer that, you can have all data together by `Customer.first.invoices.includes(:line_items)`

Comment: But how can I return all of the line_items?

Comment: @quad I have edited my answer, please check if it solves your problem.

Comment: Well that is not quite the thing, sorry for the mix up but I'm purely asking about the association chaining, is it possible or not.

Comment: Oh okay. Well for that as far as I know, and you are looking for straight answer, then `NO`, not possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96809/discussion-between-dusht-and-quad).

Answer (score 0):

`Customer.first.invoices` will return an collection (like an array) of invoices. The line_items method isn't defined for a collection, but its defined for an invoice. Try `Customer.first.invoices.first.line_items`

EDIT - If you always want the orders to include the line items, you can just do:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, -> { includes :line_items }
end 

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Comment: That is not the thing I'm wondering about, check the edit above :)

Comment: Reread 4.3.3.4 in the rails guides. I believe the second snippet of code on that page explains the behavior you are looking for! :)

Comment: But how can I "retrieve line items" this way?